# Google Sheets/JIRA Connection

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, jira

I'm trying to connect Google Sheets to JIRA to gather the data for updating reports automatically.

I'm struggling however with a couple of points in this modified script.

I want to return the component field but calling the name field returns `undefined`.

```
var components = data["issues"][id].fields.components.name;
```

If I remove the name field, then I get the following response:

```
{name=#####, self=https://www.#########/rest/api/2/component/26357, id=26357}
```

The second issue is that only a handful of issues are being rendered. As far as I can see my REST call looks OK, as does the writing to tables:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); //select active spreadsheet
sheet.getRange(2, 1, issuessss.length, 7).setValues(issuessss); // write from cell A2
break;
```

Anyone have any ideas that could help?

Answer (score 0):

The field component is an array so `components.name` does not exist (i.e components[0].name would work).

Before setting the values, try to execute a [flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) first.